# How would I combine 2 tables with no common column into 1 table in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have two tables one contains an ID, the other one contains HourlyRate and Bonus, I want to combine them the following way

| ID | HourlyRate | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.50 | 3 |
| 2 | 7.85 | 2 |
| 3 | 30.10 | 4 |

But I only get something like that by using merge, union, etc

| ID | HourlyRate | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 10.50 | 3 |
| NULL | 7.85 | 2 |
| NULL | 30.10 | 4 |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Help me understand... The desire is to produce the second table or the second table is what you are producing and that's not what you want?

Comment: The second table is what I'm producing and that's what i don't want to get.

Comment: Table one contains (1,2,3). Table two contains ((10.5,3), (7.85,2), (30.10,4)). How do you know that ID 1 should be associated to (10.5, 3) instead of (30.10, 4)?

Answer (score 1):

#### You cannot join both data sources!

From your question, you are looking to perform a join operation between both tables. But the bad thing is that joining requires to be performed over one or many columns in each table.

Besides, what is the logic behind the join operation you are trying to perform? How the row with `ID = 1` in the first table is combined with the row having Hourly `Rate = 10.50`?

#### How to solve this problem?

**First step: Adding a join column**

To solve this issue, you have to generate a new column that can be used in the join (merge join). As an example, if you need to join using the row number; *the first line in the first table is combined with the first line in the second table...*. Then, you need to add a row number column for each table.

You can add a row number column for each table using a Script Component as explained in the following articles:

- [Adding row numbers to SSIS data flows](https://richardswinbank.net/ssis/adding_row_numbers_to_ssis_dataflows)
- [HOW TO ADD A ROW NUMBER TO A DATA FLOW TASK IN SSIS 2012](https://www.hansmichiels.com/2015/11/13/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/)

Remember that you need two Script Component in your case if the ID column in the first table may contain gaps between numbers *(i.e. 1,2,3,6,7,...)*.

Another approach is to add a row number column from SQL *(if the data is stored in SQL)* is using `ROW_NUMBER()` SQL function:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (Select 0)) as row_id, *
FROM TableA
```

More details in :

- [Row Number Without Using Order By In SQL Server](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/row-number-without-using-order-by)

**Second step: Joining both data sources**

After adding a row number column, you should use a merge join component to combine both data sources. You can learn more about the merge and merge join components in the following articles:

- [SSIS Merge Join vs. Merge Transformation](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-merge-join-vs-merge-transformation/)
- [Using the Merge Join Transformation in SSIS packages](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-the-merge-join-transformation-in-ssis-packages/)